# Terraform SNS Subscription Multiple Emails

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sns

What does the formatting of multiple email addresses for the aws_sns_topic_subscription Terraform resource look like?

```
resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "target" {
  topic_arn = aws_sns_topic.some_sns_topic.arn
  protocol  = "email"
  endpoint  = "aaa@gmail.com,bbb@gmail.com"
}
```

I've tried many combinations for the endpoint parameter:

```
endpoint  = "aaa@gmail.com,bbb@gmail.com"
endpoint  = "aaa@gmail.com", "bbb@gmail.com"
endpoint  = ["aaa@gmail.com", "bbb@gmail.com"]
```

I've found nothing online or in the Terraform docs on how to do this.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`endpoint` accepts only one email address if the `protocol` is `email` type.

If you have multiple email addresses, you may want to use `for_each` to create a subscription for each address.

```
resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "target" {
  for_each  = toset(["aaa@gmail.com", "bbb@gmail.com"])
  topic_arn = aws_sns_topic.some_sns_topic.arn
  protocol  = "email"
  endpoint  = each.value
}
```

Comment: This is an amazing solution!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have used so far:

```
locals {
  emails = ["user@email.com", "user2@email.com", "user3@email.com"]
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "target" { 
  count     = length(local.emails)
  topic_arn = aws_sns_topic.some_sns_topic.arn 
  protocol  = "email" 
  endpoint  = local.emails[count.index] 
}
```